# Android layout inflator from a Adapter class not working

Tags: android, android-layout

Im trying to manipulate a button of a layout from my ImageAdapter class who extends from BaseAdapter.

here is my adapter class  :

```
public class ImageAdapterAvatar extends BaseAdapter {



 public ImageAdapterAvatar(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.avatar, null);

//do things with my gridwiew

View bouttonView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_which_contain_my_button,null);
Button bouttonValidate = (Button) bouttonView.findViewById(R.id.buttonValidate);

  }
}
```

and my activity code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_which_contain_my_button);
fragmentAdaptateur = new ImageAdapterAvatar(this);
```

the gridView works, i can do what i want, but the button not, i can get the element but when i try to manipulate like :

```
bouttonValidate.setText("hello world");
```

i got no response.

Need help~~

Answer (score 0):

Check it, may help..

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     View v = convertView;

        if (null == v) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_which_contain_my_button, parent, false);
    }else{
    //null Log 
    }
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finaly i maked the trick with this

```
Activity activity= (Activity) context;
Button bouttonValidate = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.buttonValidate);
```

Actually i can simply convert my context into activity and then call the findViewById method from the activity, then manipulate layout elements